# TextBox Mask in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, mask

How to create a Mask in TextBox Control in UWP?

I search and find this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HoveyTech.MaskedTextBox.UWP/

example of Mask: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask

How I use this nuget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what effect you want to achieve using a "Mask TextBox", maybe you are looking for the UWP [Password box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.PasswordBox) control, see the [guideline about the Password box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/password-box) to learn how to use it.

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" Width="200" MaxLength="16" Height="30" 
 IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask

Comment: Do you mean how to use this [TextBoxMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask) Property in the Windows Community Toolkit?